# How can I go about fixing the following messy dates in my .xlxs file

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following .xlxs file, I have uploaded it on google drive [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iWYTZFR_lLJCM0mhMfmLh3hfDktsr9_D/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=106220888516231692194&rtpof=true&sd=true), with 10 different dates and I was experimenting with pandas.to_datetime to clean the messy dates that I have. However I realised that the function has some limits specifically for the dates I have in row 2 (1414/01/2019) and 3 (110/05/2019).
Obviously I would like to fix the dates in row 2 and 3 to (14/01/2019) and (11/05/2019) respectively. However if this cannot be done is there a way on how I can skip over rows that have a date format that cannot be fixed with pandas.to_datetime?

```
import pandas as pd

test=pd.read_excel('Messy_Dates.xlsx', usecols=[0], header=None, skiprows = [0])
```

Comment: How do you know row 3 isn't supposed to be 10/05/2019?

Comment: _Obviously I would like to fix the dates in row 2 and 3 to ... (11/05/2019) respectively_.. - why do you think is so obvious, e.g. 110/05 may as well be 11/05 or 10/05. Basically your question is how to clean wrong input, which is not straight forward

Comment: You are correct, my mistake, I wouldn't know if it should be 11/05 or 10/05. So I guess the best option in that case would be to omit that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True` and `errors='coerce'`, so possible remove not parseable datetimes by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
test=pd.read_excel('Messy_Dates.xlsx', usecols=[0], header=None, skiprows = [0])

out = pd.to_datetime(test[0], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').dropna()
print (out)
0   2018-05-16
1   2018-05-17
4   2019-05-22
5   2019-05-24
6   2019-05-25
7   2019-05-28
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Is there a way how I can save the data omitted in a list?

Comment: There was a missing bracket `L = test.loc[(test[0], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').isna(), 0].tolist()` however it is still giving a syntax error as is.

Comment: @Justin - Sorry, use  `L = test.loc[pd.to_datetime(test[0], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').isna(), 0].tolist()`

Comment: By any chance does the `errors='coerce'` have an index? As I have additional data attributed to those dates [3 additional columns to be exact] and so I would need to omit the data that has an omitted date value

Comment: That only gave me an Index error `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed`

Comment: @Justin - Use `idx = test.index[pd.to_datetime(test[0], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').isna()].tolist()`